# T SQL Update using LAG Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using MS SQL Server.

I am trying to work out the percentage difference between two fields: 'RecordCount' and the previous 'RecordCount' that I am using the LAG function to retrieve.  However, I just keep receiving the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE  UpdateTarget
SET PercentChange = Change
FROM (SELECT CAST((RecordCount -LAG(RecordCount) 
OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated))/ CAST (LAG(RecordCount) 
OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated) AS decimal (18,2)) AS decimal (18,2))*100 Change)
FROM MyTable AS UpdateTarget;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your column in your subquery `Change` doesn't have an alias, and you have a trailing `)` and additional alias after `MyTable A`.

Comment: @Larnu updated with latest code but still receiving same error

Comment: You have two FROM clauses one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a CTE which will give a modular and more readable approach

```
;WITH UpdateTarget AS
(
SELECT CAST((RecordCount -LAG(RecordCount) 
OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated))/ CAST (LAG(RecordCount) 
OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated) AS decimal (18,2)) AS decimal (18,2))*100 AS Change, PercentChange
FROM MyTable a
)
UPDATE UpdateTarget
SET  PercentChange = Change
```